# Proof outline of a construction of injective function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be nonempty s.t. there exists $f:A\to A$ injective but not subjective. Show there is a $g:\mathbb{N} \to A$ that is injective.

Below is my proof, is this a correct approach? Anything I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Could you not just do it like this:
Take an arbitrary $a_1\in A$ and some $a_2 \in A\backslash \{a_1\}$, then $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$ since $f$ is injective. Now, if you have $a_1,\dots,a_k$, choose $a_{k+1} \in A\backslash \{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ and since $f$ is injective, it holds that $f(a_{k+1}) \neq f(a_k) \neq \dots \neq f(a_1)$. If you now define $g(n) := f(a_n)$, then $g$ is injective.

Comment: yes, thank you! I guess one thing would be to show before $a_2 \in A\backslash \{ a_1\}$ that $A$ cannot have 1 element as it is not surjective, and similarly cannot have $k$ elements in the recursion step?

Comment: yeah, since $f$ is not surjective, you can always find another element.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Why do you say that if $a_3=a_1$ then $f$ is surjective? If, say $f\colon\Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z$ is defined by$$f(n)=\begin{cases}-n&\text{ if }n\in\{-1,0,1\}\\n+1&\text{ if }n>1\\-n-1&\text{ if }n<-1,\end{cases}$$then $f$ is injective and not surjective ($\pm2\notin f(\Bbb Z)$). But, if you define $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ as you did with $a_1=1$, then $a_3=a_1$.

---

You can do it as follows. Let $A_0=A$ and let $A_1=f(A_0)=f(A)$. Since $f$ is not surjective, $A_1\ne A_0$. So, $A_1\varsubsetneq A_0$. Now, let $A_2=f(A_1)$. Since $A_1\subset A_0$,$$A_2=f(A_1)\subset f(A_0)=A_1.$$In fact, $A_2\varsubsetneq A_1$. In order to see why, take $y\in A_0\setminus A_1$; clearly, $f(y)\in A_1$, and I will prove that $f(y)\notin A_2$. If $f(y)\in A_2$, then $f(y)=f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$, for some $x\in A$. But, since $f$ is injective,$$f(y)=f\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\implies y=f(x),$$which is impossible, since $y\notin A_1=f(A)$. By the same argument, if $A_3=f(A_2)$, then $A_3\varsubsetneq A_2$ and so on. Now, for any $n\in\Bbb N$, let $g(n)$ be an element of $A_{n-1}\setminus A_n$ and then $g$ is an injective map from $\Bbb N$ into $A$.

Comment: because $f(a1) = a2$, and $f(a2) = a3 = a1$? Oh wait I see my mistake..

Comment: Is there a way to fix this proof without changing too much? Am I in the right track?

Comment: Right now, I don't see how to fix that proof without changing too much.

Comment: @korone I've added a solution.